# Can you change a 7 speed freewheel to 6 speed

Tags: freewheel

Can you change a 7 speed freewheel to a 6 speed

Comment: Could you give a little more information about your situation and why you're considering a change?

Answer (score 3):

In general, yes. They use the same thread/attachment to the hub and they are almost the same width. If you have friction shifting it will work fine, but if you have indexed shifting that will obviously not work - the spacing between cogs is different.

There's [more information here](http://sheldonbrown.com/harris/freewheels.html)